# Wordpress plugin loads css files from localhost eventhought it is live already

Tags: css, wordpress, cross-domain

I have developed a page built over Wordpress with a external plugin Media Grid. Once done, I released the site to the live page, but I have realized, that the plugin still loads its css files from an address on localhost.

The first error I see on console is

```
Font from origin 'http://locpage.loc' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.livepage.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

When I reload the page, I got another errors

```
GET http://locpage.loc/wp-content/plugins/media-grid/css/frontend.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
www.livepage.ch/:32 GET http://locpage.loc/wp-content/plugins/media-grid/js/jquery.galleria/themes/mediagrid/galleria.mediagrid.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
www.livepage.ch/:32 GET http://locpage.loc/wp-content/plugins/media-grid/js/jPlayer/skin/media.grid/jplayer.media.grid.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

When I released the page, I changed the site url in wordpress admin and also in database wp_options. How to fix this?

The page can be visited [here](http://voirestsavoir.ch).

Thank you!

**EDIT (Styles loading):**
In the plugin, I can see these files are loaded the following way.

```
////////////////////////////////////
// DYNAMICALLY CREATE THE CSS //////
////////////////////////////////////
include_once(MG_DIR . '/functions.php');

// remove the HTTP/HTTPS for SSL compatibility
$safe_baseurl = str_replace(array('http:', 'https:', 'HTTP:', 'HTTPS:'), '', MG_URL);
?>

@import url("<?php echo $safe_baseurl; ?>/css/frontend.css");

@import url("<?php echo $safe_baseurl; ?>/js/jquery.galleria/themes/mediagrid/galleria.mediagrid.css");
@import url("<?php echo $safe_baseurl; ?>/js/jPlayer/skin/media.grid/jplayer.media.grid.css");
```

Comment: Are you loading your CSS-files with `href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/css/..."` or even `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>` for the `style.css` file?

Comment: I load my styles from functions.php using wp_register_style() followed by wp_enqueue_style(). These styles (default) works, but the ones from the plugin does not.

Comment: Doesn't clearing your browser cache solve it?